# Parse string to DateTime with format "MMMM yyyy"

Tags: c#, date, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to parse a string that contains a month and a year (`"April 2017"` for example) into a `DateTime`:

```
var foo = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToParse, "MMMM yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

However the format of the result is `04/01/2017  00:00:00` instead of `April 2017`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, you missed that DateTime does not have an implicit format. That's why you have to parse and format its value.

Comment: You missed the fact that `foo` is the struct returned by `DateTime.ParseExact()`, which is an object of type `DateTime`. *It has no format*. You are stringifying it with the default format. Google DateTime.ToString() to find out how to format DateTime as a string in any way you like.

Comment: 04/01/2017 is April 2017, or am I missing something?

Comment: `foo.ToString("MMMM yyyy")`. voilà, you got your "format" back.

Comment: what purpose of converting sting into string and then back?

Comment: To add to Tim Schmelter's comment "...parsing your string to DateTime worked without a problem": but it will only continue to work without a problem if your code runs in an English culture.  It would be better to use the ParseExact overload that makes the culture explicit.

Comment: @demo - the usual workflow is: convert `string` to `DateTime` as soon as possible, work with `DateTime` all you want and then convert it back to `string` as late as possible, for example shortly before displaying it to a human.

Comment: Ah I see the problem now. Thank you all for the quick answers
@MichaelMcGriff : m/d/yyyy default formating i guess ?

Comment: @Corak, I disagree, normal workflow should be, don't store DateTime as string, store as DateTime, work with as DateTime, only convert to string for display.

Comment: @YthioCsi - "default" formating is probably defined by `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: @Kevin - agreed. If *you* control how the data enters your system (read it from a db or some other kind of typed storage), then by all means, have it in as precise a datatype as possible. The "convert `string` to `DateTime`" part was meant for the situation, where something that *should* be a `DateTime` enters your system as `string`. Maybe a user input or from a CSV or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

*"I'm trying to parse a string"* and parsing your string to `DateTime` worked without a problem.

A `DateTime` has a value and no format, if you want to get again another sting which represents that `DateTime` in a specific format you have to use `DateTime.ToString`.

For example:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("April 2017", "MMMM yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
string monthAndYear = dt.ToString("MMMM yyyy"); // same as your original string "April 2017"
```

Answer (score 0):

`04/01/2017  00:00:00` is the formatted output with **default** formatting of the value of the DateTime instance you parsed.

DateTime does not have an implicit format.

If you want to display it in the form you mentioned you need to do something like `foo.ToString("MMMM yyyy")`